# Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred

Tags: asp.net, wcf, deserialization

I have a WCF Service call updating the Members table passing in a POCO.  I'm getting the following error -

```
Server Error.
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter :memberEntity. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type EventInventory.Applications.WebService.Jetson.Entities.MemberEntity. Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 86, position 64.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter :memberEntity. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type EventInventory.Applications.WebService.Jetson.Entities.MemberEntity. Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 86, position 64.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Source Error:


Line 3175:        
Line 3176:        public TMResale.Identity.Member.MemberUpdateResponse Update(TMResale.Identity.Member.MemberEntity memberEntity) {
Line 3177:            return base.Channel.Update(memberEntity);
Line 3178:        }
Line 3179:        


Source File: c:\Source\Dev\TicketsNow Perf\EventInventory.Applications\Web\TMResale\TMResale\Service References\Identity.Member\Reference.cs    Line: 3177

Stack Trace:


[ProtocolException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter :memberEntity. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type EventInventory.Applications.WebService.Jetson.Entities.MemberEntity. Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 86, position 64.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14539490
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   TMResale.Identity.Member.MemberService.Update(MemberEntity memberEntity) +0
   TMResale.Identity.Member.MemberServiceClient.Update(MemberEntity memberEntity) in c:\Source\Dev\TicketsNow Perf\EventInventory.Applications\Web\TMResale\TMResale\Service References\Identity.Member\Reference.cs:3177
   TMResale.Models.Membership.MembershipModel.UpdateEmail() in c:\Source\Dev\TicketsNow Perf\EventInventory.Applications\Web\TMResale\TMResale\Models\Membership\MembershipModel.cs:427
   TMResale.Controllers.MembershipController.UpdateEmail(MembershipModel membershipModel) in c:\Source\Dev\TicketsNow Perf\EventInventory.Applications\Web\TMResale\TMResale\Controllers\MembershipController.cs:80
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +838059
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +838059
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +838644
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: This can indicate there was an error with the message formatting.  Can you post the POCO object you're trying to serialize?  If you're able to capture the message itself that would be helpful itself.

Comment: Found it! The issue was with a LoggingMessageInspector Behavior. After it was turned off, the WCF call is working fine! :)